# Collapse Dataframe onto NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that computes values for certain integers in its index, and for other index integers displays NaN (intentional behavior).

I would like to collapse the dataframe so that it will "fall" on the NaNs, replacing them with all of the valid values.

An example is below:

```
1 -0.037979       NaN -0.248677
2       NaN       NaN -0.058432
3  0.007599  0.007599  0.036740
4       NaN       NaN  0.322239
5  0.007595       NaN  0.036711
6       NaN       NaN  0.036707
7  0.053155  0.053155  0.322011
```

Desired Outcome:

```
1                     -0.248677
2                     -0.058432
3                      0.036740
4  0.007595            0.322239
5  0.007595  0.007599  0.036711
6  0.007595  0.007599  0.036707
7  0.053155  0.053155  0.322011
```

I have tried to replace the NaNs with zero values and arrange them up above the valid data with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.notnull))
Out[111]: 
          1         2         3
1       NaN       NaN -0.248677
2       NaN       NaN -0.058432
3       NaN       NaN  0.036740
4 -0.037979       NaN  0.322239
5  0.007599       NaN  0.036711
6  0.007595  0.007599  0.036707
7  0.053155  0.053155  0.322011
```